# Expo can’t solve the depencencies when I try to run my application with expo go on Android emulation or real device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, web, expo

I have a problem with my application.

After working in the web for a while I can’t run my application with 'npm run android', when I try got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2z2a.png).

My App.tsx file is this :

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Appearance } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import {
  Provider as PaperProvider
} from "react-native-paper";
import Navigation from "./src/routing/Navigation";
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./src/redux/store";
import { themePaper } from "./src/theme/themes";

import { fr, registerTranslation } from 'react-native-paper-dates';
registerTranslation('fr', fr);

import '@expo/match-media';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
moment.locale('fr');


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <PaperProvider
        theme={themePaper}
      >
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          {/* <Navbar/> */}
          <Navigation />
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </PaperProvider>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
}
```

and my package.json file contain the dependency

```
 {
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "dev": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web:dev": "expo start --web",
    "web:build": "npx expo export:web",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.27.0",
    "@editorjs/header": "^2.7.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@expo/match-media": "^0.4.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-image": "~1.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-network": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "merge-anything": "^5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^1.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-editor-js": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-big-calendar": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1298.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.2",
    "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.18.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-native-web-lottie": "^1.4.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.7",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Do you have an idea of why it work in web but don't on android ?

I tried the app on another device and I get the same error, another project is working on my environments.